# Вывод сообщений в шахматном порядке

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно сделать примерно такую форму записи:

```
┌───────────────────────┐
│┌────┐                 │
||Left|                 │
│└────┘          ┌─────┐|
│                │Right│|
|┌────┐          └─────┘│
│|Left|                 |
|└────┘          ┌─────┐|
│                │Right│|
|┌────┐          └─────┘│
||Left|                 |
│└────┘          ┌─────┐|
│                │Right│|
|                └─────┘│
└───────────────────────┘
```

Использую следующий код:

```css
.msg-block {
    display: grid;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 40;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    font: 1.4em Arial sans-serif;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
}

.item-left {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    justify-self: start;
}

.item-right {
    grid-column-start: 2;
    justify-self: end;
}
```

```html
<div class="msg-block">
            <div class="item-right">Right</div>
            <div class="item-left">Left</div>
            <div class="item-right">Right</div>
            <div class="item-left">Left</div>
            <div class="item-right">Right</div>
            <div class="item-left">Left</div>
</div>
```

Однако это работает не так, как нужно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
.msg-block {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.msg-block .item {}

.msg-block .item span {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background: lightblue;
}

.msg-block .item:nth-child(even) {}

.msg-block .item:nth-child(odd) {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="msg-block">
  <div class="item"><span>Right</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span>Left</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span>Right</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span>Left</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span>Right</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span>Left</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: А как добавить border и/или background вокруг текста?

Answer (score 2):

```css
.msg-block {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid blue;

  max-width: 10em;
  margin: auto;
}

.item-left, .item-right {
  clear: both;

  background: silver;
  border-radius: 1em;
  padding: .25em .5em;
}

.item-left {
  float: left;
}

.item-right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="msg-block">
  <div class="item-right">Right</div>
  <div class="item-left">Left</div>
  <div class="item-right">Right</div>
  <div class="item-left">Left</div>
  <div class="item-right">Right</div>
  <div class="item-left">Left</div>
</div>
```